# how to get all the child category name in a specified category name?

Tags: wordpress

now, supposed the specified category name is "product". which have three layer sub-category.the structure is like the following:

```
product one
  - product two
   - - product three
    - - - product four
```

now i want to output all the subcategory names in the sidebar.php of my theme. how do i do? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This page [on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) explains how to do this, using the parent category id in the "child_of" parameter. Should be what you want.